# How to get the closest signed type which covers all the range of current unsigned type?

Tags: c++, std

In the template I have a type for index (`IndexType`) which is `unsigned` type and need to create a member for offset which could be negative but should contain all the range for the initial unsigned type. In practice this means that it must be the next larger integer signed size.

At the same time I don't want to allocate the largest possible signed type like `std::ptrdiff_t` to save space, since `signed short` could be much better fit for `unsigned char` in terms of memory.

I can make very complex `std::conditional` with `sizeof`s for all possible combinations, but this will be too verbose. Is there any straightforward solution for this?

At the moment I don't need sizes larger than `std::ptrdiff_t`, so the quest "what if you need the size larger than all build-in primitive integer types?" could be postponed.

```
template <typename IndexType> // Here I get unsigned type of index
struct Offset {
    IndexType offs; // Here I need a type which will be signed, but enough to keep unsigned values of IndexType, but not unnecessary large
};
```

Comment: A custom type trait is normally how this is handled.  Yo are going to have to decide what happens when you have an unsigned long long as there is no signed type that can fit that range built into the standard.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thank you for the edit; I have no idea why it was blocked for edit for me after creation. And I was able to edit after that, so I added the answer to your comment above, let's keep this out of the question for now how to handle offsets for sizes of unsigned long long int. This interesting one, but let's focus on it in another question. What do you mean with "custom type trait"? Do you mean the approach I described as "verbose" or something else?

Comment: what if you just - stupidly simple - create a template and instantiate the template with all integer types?
https://godbolt.org/z/n833e6Pfd

Comment: @DamirTenishev Yes.  I've added an answer that shows one way to do so.

Comment: @Raildex, seems fine, but my **Offset** template is a complicated structure which I don't want to replicate. Of course, I can use a kernel part in your way and inherit from it, but with this amount of code duplication there is a an easy way for mistake. Thank you for the idea, anyway, could help in other situations.

Comment: @Raildex You miss some cases there.  For instance `char` can be unsigned or signed, and if it is unsigned then you've missed handling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't worried about the case when the unsigned type is as large as the largest signed type there is really only three cases you need to check.  If the size is 1, then get a 2 size type, If the size is 2, get a 4 size type, otherwise just go with the max signed type.  One way to do that is to leverage a function to get the type like:

```
auto promote_type(std::unsigned_integral auto type)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof(type) == 1)      return int16_t();
    else if constexpr (sizeof(type) == 2) return int32_t();
    else                                  return int64_t();
}
    
template <typename T>
using promoted_type = decltype(promote_type(T{}));
    
int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<promoted_type<unsigned>, int64_t>);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In practice the number of cases is really not so large on the usual platforms:

```
template <std::unsigned_integral T>
using Offset = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) == 1, int16_t,
    std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) == 2, int32_t, int64_t>>;
```

You mentioned this would be "too verbose" but it really is quite concise.